# New Line In Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL string in my java code:

```
"Started: "+billingDBTime+" FIRST\n"+"Category:Content\n"+"\n" + ";"+"$Value:599\n"+"\n" ;
```

I would like to insert this string to the DB and get it from the DB.

As you all know `'\n'` indicates a new line, How can I indicate a new line in the DB when I insert this string into the DB?

And how can I check that after insert it into the DB?

To Be more clear the string should look like :

Started: 2013-04-10 11:43:21 FIRST
Category:Content

;$Value:599

what is replacing "\n" in Sql ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you need to indicate new line in DB..you can just insert the string whatever you have in DB as it is ...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in TSQL by inserting the character codes directly in the string. I usually put this in a variable to make it easier to use.

```
DECLARE @crlf char(2) = Char(13) + Char(10)

SELECT  'Started: ' + billingDBTime + ' FIRST' + @crlf + 'Category:Content' + @crlf + @crlf + ';' + '$Value:599' + @crlf + @crlf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Every "line" you insert into DB called `row`. In your case, you have to insert 3 rows into DB. You can use `INSERT INTO` & `SELECT` method to insert/get rows from DB.

Since you didn't show your table structure, I can't give you further advice about how to write your own SQL precisely.

Read http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_quickref.asp for a quick SQL reference.

Comment: Thanks fro your response. the table is a regular table that have 3 colums.

id | trigger | string

The string with the "\n" should be added to the String column.